# Why ever have more than one Sidekiq client connection for a single-threaded process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, redis, sidekiq, unicorn

Simple question about setting the number of Sidekiq client connections to redis (via, e.g.,  `Sidekiq.configure_client do |config| { config.redis = { size: 5 } }`).

Why would you ever set it to more than 1 for a single-threaded process?  Say you're running a Unicorn web server - then I can't see why each Unicorn process would need more than 1 connection.  My thought process is that since the Unicorn process blocks on I/O, it can't really issue network requests with any real concurrency (e.g. to redis), and therefore more than 1 connection is pointless (unless you're using EventMachine or something like this)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your own threads within unicorn you'll need more than one. Also the connection pool is lazy so if you only need one connection it will only create one connection.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks much and thanks for Sidekiq!  Love it.